# .NET Core IdentityServer4 Null ClientId/ClientName in LogoutRequest (Using SAML2P)

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4, saml-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using IdentityServer4 with Brock Allen's QuickStart project on asp.netcore2.
I've actually successfully developped a Saml SSO Idp. The Sign-on part works perfectly.
But for the log-out, as I have multiple Service Providers, I need to get the ClientId or ClientName in the Logout action controller (to log the user out of our own application). 
So I'm trying to use IIdentityServerInteractionService which is injected in the controller.

```
LogoutRequest logoutRequest = _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId).Result;
```

But here is what I get in logoutRequest :

[logout request without clientId or clientName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1giH.png)

I know ClientIds contains the ClientId i'm looking for, but as it also takes all the other connected Service Providers Ids in, I can't use it.

I've used Fiddler to look at what is happening behind all of this, and it looks like there isn't any Saml in the logout request the SP send, am I wrong ?

I've seen many people who've successfully used LogoutRequest, but they mostly use openId-connect.
So I presume there as to be with a bad configuration on my side, or maybe Saml2 is inappropriate for this ?

Connection to my database is fine, Clients work perfectly for the SSO part as I've said before.
I'm actually quite new to asp.net core and all of this so sorry if this looks confused.

Here is my Idsrv4 config in the Startup file:

```
services.AddDbContext(db =>
db.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly)));
services.AddScoped<ISamlConfigurationDbContext, SamlConfigurationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"),
                        sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            .AddSamlPlugin(ConfigureSaml)
            .AddServiceProviderStore<ServiceProviderStore>()
            .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>();
```

So in summary here is my question : Why can't I get the ClientId/Name ? And how can I get it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of the SAML component are you using? I've tried with the latest and the ClientId is returned by the IdentityServer interaction service.

Comment: @ScottBrady I'm curently using version 2.2.0 preview2 of the Rsk.IdentityServer4.Saml nugget package

Comment: preview3 was released yesterday which is what I used to confirm that ClientId was returned

Comment: Actually I tried a few minuts ago with preview3, but it doesn't look to change anything for my issue... I wonder what am I doing wrong. Have you any idea where I should look at ? If needed I can send more code samples

Comment: Check out the SAML sample on GitHub, that demonstrates the core of what we support in our SAML component: https://github.com/RockSolidKnowledge/Samples.IdentityServer4.Saml2pIntegration